# How to show the hidden browser on a running program

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am running an automation program (browser is hidden from the beginning) but from time to time I need to check some stuff visually on the browser. Is there any way to make `options.headless = False` or any other way to make the browser visible **without** starting the
browser from zero / all over?

```
driver_path = "browser/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path)
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

Think about this even if it was possible you would have done :

```
options.headless = False
```

now again you would need to pass this option to browser specific driver right ?

and in middle of the program if you do it,

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, options=options)
```

there will be a new instance of browser driver created.

So I would suggest either go totally with headless mode or with UI